# Morphisms between $\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, automorphism-group

Is there an easy way to see that $\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ are not isomorphic ?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the center of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ is $\{I, -I\}$, whereas the center of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$ is $\{qI : q \in \mathbf{Q}^\times\}$, which is infinite.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn: I just realized I meant $\mathbf{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbf{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Boccherini, $PGL_2(\Bbb Z)$ has infinite index in $PGL_2(\Bbb Q)$.